# Run facebook app locally in wamp

Tags: php, facebook, wamp

I'm trying to run my facebook app on wamp. I downloaded my source code from git and copied all the files in the www directory (wamp/www) and named the file mynewherokuapp. I set in facebook  website>url>http://localhost/mynewherokuapp/ . Why do i get this error: "An error occurred. Please try later.".

Comment: Wondered how facebook allowed you to specify `localhost` as website url. Are you sure it has been saved successfully?

Comment: FB does allow it, I'm using it regularly while developing apps.

Comment: Is canvas URL you provide (http://localhost/mynewherokuapp) can be opened in browser and not working only on facebook.com?

Comment: The moment i open (local/mynewherokuapp), i would go to the facebook error page." Error An error occurred. Please try later".

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to place an entry in your `hosts` file mapping a fake domain name to `127.0.0.1`
something like :

```
127.0.0.1    fbDev.local.com
```

Obviously `fbDev.local.com` is not a real domain owned by you, but your system will treat all calls to that domain as if they were to localhost (127.0.0.1).
Then in your app settings you place your fake domain in the URL fields.

Comment: Erm. Where can i find this **hosts** file? I'm really new to everything.

Comment: what operating system do you use? This wiki page will help you find your hosts file. [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file))

Comment: have you found your hosts file?

Comment: Yes, i have found it and at host file under(# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.), i added this (# 127.0.0.1      fbDev.local.com). However, i'm still unable to open the facebook app. But this time, i noticed that there is a error page before the facebook error page. Anyone knows how i can stop at the error page to get a good look at it? I think i saw something like- Undefined index: HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO ...at line4...

Comment: ok - first of all the hash sign (#) at the beginning of the line in your hosts file is commenting out that line.  Im not sure what the second error is - have you got SSL configured correctly on your local server?

Comment: I removed the # sign and now it is like this - 127.0.0.1      fbDev.local.com , in my host file. I enabled ssl from (wamp tray icon)>apache>apache modules>ssl_module. Still not working...

Comment: what happens when you navigate to your url directly? - that means not through facebook.

Comment: Do you mean through local/mynewherokuapp? The app have a host on heroku too named https://furious-window-8157.herokuapp.com/ . And it is running fine when i access https://furious-window-8157.herokuapp.com/ if i set it was website url in facebook.

Comment: I see a fast flash to an error page, which immediately loads to the facebook page with this message: Error An error occurred. Please try later.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6433/discussion-between-lix-and-user1050548)